# what is __KERNEL__ used for in linux kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel

who can explain what does the following code means?

if `__KERNEL__` is not defined, define following macros.
when and where define `__KERNEL__` ?

```
/* only for userspace compatibility */
#ifndef __KERNEL__

/* IP6 Hooks */
/* After promisc drops, checksum checks. */
#define NF_IP6_PRE_ROUTING  0
/* If the packet is destined for this box. */
#define NF_IP6_LOCAL_IN     1
/* If the packet is destined for another interface. */
#define NF_IP6_FORWARD      2
/* Packets coming from a local process. */
#define NF_IP6_LOCAL_OUT        3
/* Packets about to hit the wire. */
#define NF_IP6_POST_ROUTING 4
#define NF_IP6_NUMHOOKS     5
#endif /* ! __KERNEL__ */
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

When you compile your kernel, `__KERNEL__` is defined on the command line.

User-space programs need access to the kernel headers, but some of the info in kernel headers is intended only for the kernel.  Wrapping some statements in an `#ifdef __KERNEL__/#endif` block ensures that user-space programs don't see those statements.

Comment: This is very handy... but can we rely on it existing? Where is it documented?

Answer (score 7):

I used [Google](http://www.google.com) to search for `__KERNEL__` and found [this](http://www.issociate.de/board/post/407739/__KERNEL___and___MODULE__.html).

> The `__KERNEL__` macro is defined because there is programs (like libraries) than include kernel code and there is many things that you don't want them to include. So most modules will want the `__KERNEL__` macro to be enabled.

Comment: ... Which is talking about "module" as in "compiling your own kernel module". Many people who wonder about this macro are not compiling anything that wants to be part of the kernel, so maybe spell out that they don't want or need this.

Answer (score 2):

The same code is used in userspace `iptables` application (and possibly `glibc` and others), hence there is a protection for non-kernel code.

Comment: The content of #ifndef __KERNEL__/#endif block is used by userspace. Kernel would't see these.

Comment: I like this answer because it includes the reason *why* one would use the ifdef. (what I'm wondering is, where is this cpp flag actually documented -- or else how can we rely on it in new shared kernel/user code? I suppose we can rely on it because it's in this old code that hasn't changed in decades?)