# Using gcc to compile userspace application using linux kernel headers

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I have a really simple c program that I want to compile using gcc, importing from linux kernel headers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <linux/random.h>

int main(){
    int rand;
    get_random_bytes(&rand,sizeof(rand));
    printf("%d",rand);
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried to compile this program using the following command:

```
gcc rand.c -D__KERNEL__ -isystem /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build/include
```

But I get a bunch of errors (below). What am I missing?:

```
/usr/src/kernels/4.9.8-201.fc25.x86_64/include/linux/linkage.h:7:25: fatal error: asm/linkage.h: No such file or directory
 #include <asm/linkage.h>
```

Comment: Why did you put `-D__KERNEL__ -isystem` and what happens if you take them out?

Comment: @tripleee Because I found that pattern after some googling around.....

`gcc rand.c` gives `rand.c:(.text+0x1a): undefined reference to get_random_bytes'`

Comment: You [only want `-D__KERNEL__` when you are compiling something which should become part of the kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744758/what-is-kernel-used-for-in-linux-kernel/4748784). This is clearly intended as a simple standalone program.

Comment: Ok thanks, that makes sense. I was only wanting to write a user-space program to stub out some parts of a kernel driver I am working on. Doesn't look like that approach will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From some quick Google searches, it seems like `get_random_bytes` might be a private function only usable from within the kernel.

How about you try using `getrandom` instead?    Here is the documentation of `getrandom`:

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrandom.2.html