# Linux Kernel #ifdef directive available set by kbuild?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, directive, conditional-compilation, kbuild

Is there a Linux Kernel `#ifdef` directive for conditional compilation available, which is set by the kernel build system (kbuild)?

**Usecase**:

I have a source code file with register map entries for a SoC and with functions used by a Kernel driver. This file shall be includable by userspace programs as well to use the register map entries:

myheader.h:

```
...
#define REGENTRY1   0x0001
#define REGENTRY2   0x0002
.....
#ifdef ANY_KERNEL_DIRECTIVE???
   firstkernelspacefunc();
   ....
#endif
```

Or maybe there are other solutions to this usecase?

Comment: For me,  `__KERNEL__` of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744758/what-is-kernel-used-for-in-linux-kernel) post solved this problem

Comment: There is a split inside the kernel, UAPI headers are specifically provided for user space programs that communicate with kernel.